# JSP application design: where to set application-wide values

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, configuration, persistence, servletcontextlistener

In a Java web application, where is the best place to set *(or best mechanism to use in setting)* a string (or strings) for use, application-wide, which should never change while the application is running, and most likely never after it is installed on a given server?

One thing that would be key in this is that I want to be able to access it anywhere (in a Java Class -OR- in a JSP), as this would be for things like an application name, URL, address, telephone number, etc.

I believe the *"easiest"* would be to use `application.setAttribute()` in every single JSP (or perhaps in a global include file or such), but this hardly makes sense, as it never changes - why keep setting it? However, setting it in the application *context* would offer the ability to use EL expressions or `application.getAttribute()` to retrieve the value - is there a better way or a better place to set attributes like this? somehow in web.xml? not sure why it's so hard to find... maybe I just don't know the question to ask Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://public%20class%20Config%20implements%20ServletContextListener%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20@Override%20%20%20%20%20public%20void%20contextInitialized%28ServletContextEvent%20event%29%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Do%20stuff%20during%20server%20startup.%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20@Override%20%20%20%20%20public%20void%20contextDestroyed%28ServletContextEvent%20event%29%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Do%20stuff%20during%20server%20shutdown.%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%7D).

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        Data data = createItSomehow();
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("data", data);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

}
```

It'll be available in EL scope by `${data}`.

Comment: three questions: (1) do I just add this class to my project and it will work, or do I have to reference it somewhere special? (2) how do I access it in a Java Class? `servletContext.getAttribute("data")` or something? and (3) how many times / how often is this run? only once per application? once per session? once per servlet initialization?

Comment: 1) Yes, assuming that you're on at least Servlet 3.0. Otherwise you need to register it as `<listener>` in `web.xml`. 2) What do you think yourself? :) It's set as servlet context attribute, so it should also be available as servlet context attribute. 3) Once on webapp's startup, like as you asked.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into this - I'm pretty familiar with `get/setAttribute()` in the _session_ and _request_ objects and even _pageContext_, I've heard of `application.get/setAttribute()`, but I've not seen much mention of any _servletContext_ object yet - still somewhat new to the Java World, I guess :)

Comment: `ServletContext` in Servlet code == `application` in JSP code.

Comment: Do you want to access the value in your non-servlet classes ? If you do, then it will take some more code. Please ask us if you want to see it.

Comment: @rickz: Just make the `Data` example in my answer a singleton-like class (static final class or enum).

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to access it via a single statement or EL expression in ANY file that can contain Java or HTML --- I have been programming for a few months here (a lot of CSS, Javascript and basic Java coding), coming from a primarily .Net world and for the most part desktop application development background, so I'm not entirely sure what makes a class a servlet class vs non-servlet. We're using Spring and Hibernate and as a team we are taking over from another team that did the initial development many years ago. The project is basically updating the code and methodologies.

Comment: Uh, just a class which doesn't `extends HttpServlet` (and hence doesn't have `ServletContext` at its hands and so forth). Last but not least, I suggest you to go through [our `servlets` tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). It contains lot of valuable information and links to high quality tutorials.

Comment: In the .Net world, you can access the "Current" Servlet context from a class library. We can do the same in Java. But we have to do coding ourselves.

Comment: @rickz: .NET (MVC) is not comparable to JSP/Servlet. It's more comparable to JSF. In JSF, there's the `FacesContext`. JSP/Servlet is more comparable to classic ASP.

Comment: This is working for JSPs, but I'm not seeing how to use it in the Spring MVC controllers or other classes - feel free to help me out there if you can :)

Comment: I don't do Spring MVC. I do JSF. Just ask a new question in Spring MVC tag.